# Motivation behind the classification of PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the reasoning/motivation behind classifying PDEs into elliptic, parabolic, and hyperbolic classes in a particular way.
More precisely, though the definition of this classification purely looks algebraic in nature(using the so called discriminants), what makes the solutions of PDEs in the same class behave similarly?
Classification based on linearity (i.e. linear, semi linear, fully nonlinear)is more intuitive to understand. Amongst the second order linear PDEs, the so-called elliptic, parabolic, and hyperbolic PDEs differ in their solution behaviour. Thus, the classification based on discriminant puts the PDEs with similar solution patterns in one group and makes more sense. 
It's surprising to see that just a classification purely based on the algebraic structure of the differential operator, precisely puts PDEs with similar behaviour in one class.
Who came up with this classification? What tempted/motivated him/her to come up with this classification?

Any references/comments are appreciated.

Comment: Practically: the classification tells you which sort of boundary conditions are appropriate to have a well posed problem. Elliptic: Dirichlet/ Neumann on closed surface surrounding the solution volume. Parabolic: Dirichlet/ Neumann on open surface. Hyperbolic: Cauchy data on an open surface

Comment: @Sal Cauchy Problem for heat equation is well-posed, but it is not hyperbolic.

Comment: Are you certain of that? There is something about the characteristics of the PDEs and relation to Cauchy data- I will think about it

Comment: @Sal Yes I am.. See Evan's PDE book section 2.3 for details..

Comment: That is too fast I think: the uniqueness only holds for solutions with a growth rate as $x\to\pm \infty$ restriction. Without this restriction there are infinitely many solutions. It's right there in Evan's 2.3 remark (32). It's also clear that on any finite interval, there are no unique solutions to the heat equation using only Cauchy data, because the function or its normal derivative must be specified along the boundary